# Hide Specific Text From List Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, append, submit, hide

Each time I click on a text, it will hide all but I want to hide only the one I clicked on by using $(this) but it's not working. Any tips?

Here is the html portion

```
<input type="text"><input type="submit" value="go">
<p></p>
```

This is the jQuery portion

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(':submit').click(function(){
    var userInput = $(':text').val();
    $('p').append(userInput + "<br><br>");
});
$('p').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2SJ87/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you again need that p tag to show
You can use the html() function to clear the inner text and not hide it.

```
     $('p').click(function(){
        $(this).html('');
     });
```

.hide() will not show again till you display:block or .show()

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2SJ87/1/
If this is not what you want then please comment.

Comment: Tried your fiddle but it hides all the p instead of the p that was clicked on.

Comment: Yes. thats because I am not adding extra divs to the code. Or appending to it. I used a single <p> tag. We should have used append p instead. Then we need to have .hide() with it

Answer (score 1):

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2SJ87/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':submit').click(function(){
        var userInput = $(':text').val();
        $('p').append('<span>'+userInput +'<span>'+ "<br><br>");
    });
    $(document).on('click','p span',function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```